# How to repair the smart data? Is there some programe?

Tags: 12.04

I already tried but i simply stops at the midle and turns off the computer and doesn't solves anything. Disk type ext4.

Answer (score 0):

That means your disk is hosed. Buy a new one :)

Comment: I bought my pc this year.

Comment: Time to invoke your warranty then :)

Comment: I don't got the paper.

Comment: Back to my original answer than. The disk is hosed, buy a new one.